# Passing an object argument to a dynamic button_click eventHandler in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I am developing a website using VB.net.

This website contains a page with a **textbox** that only accepts n number and a **submit button**.

Once the user enter the value of n in the corresponding textbox and click on submit, he will be transferred to another page with n textboxes and n "Add space" buttons below each textbox that are created dynamically.

The "Add space" button is used to add "_______" to the textbox above it along with the existing text that the user already typed.

Now, in order to update each textbox with the space value, I need to pass the corresponding textbox as an argument to the "Add space" event handler which I cannot do.

I have already read about the CommandArgument idea but the problem with it is that it only accepts String values while I need textboxes to be passed instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include any relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send `TextBox.ID` as `CommandArgument`. Then you can get `TextBox` via `Page.FindControl()` method in your command handler.

```
    protected void OnButtonCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = Page.FindControl((string)e.CommandArgument) as TextBox;
        // do something with textbox
    }
```

Sorry for C# in my example, but you can easily convert it to VB.